# Metaclass issue with the ftp class

Tags: matlab, metaclass

I would like to obtain the [metaclass](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html) of some Matlab built-in classes, and I have a problem with the `@ftp` class : the class is seen by `which` but not by the metaclass system:

```
>> which('ftp')
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/matlab/iofun/@ftp/ftp.m  % ftp constructor
```

but

```
>> ?ftp

ans = 

  0x0 class array with properties:

    Name
    Description
    ...
```

I get the same empty result with [`meta.class.fromName`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.fromname.html).

Let me precise that other classes, for instance the `@serial` class, are found by both `which` and the metaclass system:

```
>> which('serial')
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/matlab/iofun/@serial/serial.m  % serial constructor
```

and

```
>> ?serial

ans = 

  class with properties:

                     Name: 'serial'
              Description: ''
                         ...
```

Why is it so ? Is it a bug or a feature ?

If that has some kind of importance, I'm running Matlab R2016a on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ftp` is actually an old-style class (uses the `@classname` folder system combined with a non-`classdef` constructor). In this style, you have the following file structure:

```
@ftp
    ftp.m       <--- Constructor (regular m-file, non-classdef)
    ascii.m     <--- Methods
    binary.m            |
    ...                 V
    delete.m
```

Compared to the new-style of classes (`classdef`), there are several limitations of these old classes including the fact that they do not work with meta-classes.

> Keep in mind that if you write classes in the old style, the following features, available in the new framework, are not supported: protected, abstract, static/constant, sealed, or hidden methods or properties; single file class definitions; events; handle classes; packages; special set and get methods; object.method() syntax; or **meta-classes**.

The new style of classes (`classdef`) [can *still* use the `@classname` class folders](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html) with the exception that the constructor file is now a `classdef` file. For these types of classes (such as `serial`), meta-classes *are* supported.

Comment: You're right that `ftp` is an old-style class, and that this is why it doesn't support meta-class functionality. But that's a completely separate issue from the fact that it uses an @-folder. @-folders are part of both the old and new (classdef) style classes. `serial` is not at all "hybrid", it's fully a new style class that happens to use an @-folder.

Comment: @SamRoberts Oh I see your comment on the "hybrid" statement. Updated to be a little clearer. Thanks!